# Why `make install` is deleting library files *.so generated by `make`?

Tags: makefile, compilation, poco-libraries

I am compiling C++ Poco libraries. I do

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../
make
make install
```

At `make install` I get an error

```
 "path/poco/instDir/lib/libPocoEncodingsd.so.60".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake_install.cmake:50 (include)


Makefile:85: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error
```

Basically the file `libPocoEncodingsd.so.60` is created with `make` but then `make install` deletes it.

Why is that?

If I do not run `make install` the folder inside the installation path is not created and all the `*.h` files are not copied there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because:

```
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./
```

means that you are installing over the top of the build directory itself,
with the result that for each filename in the cmake command:

```
  file(INSTALL DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib" TYPE SHARED_LIBRARY FILES
    "path/poco/instDir/lib/libPocoEncodingsd.so.60"
    "path/poco/instDir/lib/libPocoEncodingsd.so"
    )
```

the source and destination files are the same. Cmake preemptively deletes the
destination file to replace it with the source file. Which means it has deleted
the *source* file. Hence your failure.

This behaviour may be a bug in cmake. On the face of it, if it checks and finds that the
destination file exists and has the same timestamp as the source file, it should consider
the destination file up to date and not attempt to replace it. But I haven't delved into that. Installing on top of your build directory is reasonably classified
under *Don't do that*.

Conventionally on Unix-like OSes, locally built packages shall be installed to
`/usr/local`. That's what `/usr/local` is for. Cmake, like other source package
deployment tools, respects this convention by default. So if you simply run:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../
make
sudo make install  # Or however you run `make install` as root.
```

then the `poco` libraries will be installed in `/usr/local/lib` and the headers
in `/usr/local/include/Poco`. `/usr/local/lib` is a default library search path for the
linker  and `/usr/local/include` is a default header search path for the compiler.

If for some reason you don't want to install to the default prefix, then
choose some:

```
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/not/in/the/build/dir
```

and you will avoid this problem.

Comment: So `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./` is the destination for `make install` not for `make` (which is actually the current directory: isn't it?). Also `make install` makes a copy of the library files from one path to another, deleting the files in the destination but since the two paths are the same, first deleting the files in the destination means deleting the files to be copied. So it is not able to conclude the installation process which consists of the copy of these files. Correct?

Comment: Is `.././configure --prefix=./` the equivalent of `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./`?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi Correct!

Comment: Another stupid question: how `make install` is creating the headers in the `include` directory? It seems that sometimes running `make`, `make install` and then `make` again works in fact it is recreating the original files. Sometimes some headers are created (maybe not all of them or maybe depends on the included in your application) some times some of them are missing. Are they just a copy from the source or there is a deeper step? Do you know when they are created?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi As with the libraries, installing the headers should boil down simply to
copying each header from its source location to <install_prefix>/include/Poco, if it is not already up to date.
`make install` does that for me, but I haven't looked into what happens if
I install over my build directory (which in your case seems to be a subdirectory
of the *source* directory), and I just wouldn't have much hope of that working
out well.